# Check if item in text file in JSON format Android Studio

Tags: java, android, json, file, gson

I'm trying to check if `config1` exists in a text file, I'm using Google's Gson library.

My JSON file :

```
{
       "maps":{
          "config2":{
             "component1":"url1",
             "component2":"url1",
             "component3":"url1"
          },
          "config1":{
             "component1":"url1",
             "component2":"url1",
             "component3":"url1"
          }
       }
    }
```

Loading :

```
public void load() throws IOException {

        File file = getContext().getFileStreamPath("jsonfile.txt");
        
        FileInputStream fis = getContext().openFileInput("jsonfile.txt");
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(isr);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }

        String json = sb.toString();

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Data data = gson.fromJson(json, Data.class);
        componentURL= data.getMap().get("config1").get("component1");
```

Saving :

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
webViewActivity.Data data = gson.fromJson(json, webViewActivity.Data.class);

Map<String, String> configTest = data.getMap().get("config1");
        
data.getMap().get("config1").put(component, itemUrl);

String json = gson.toJson(data);

String filename = "jsonfile.txt";

FileOutputStream outputStream;

try {
   outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   outputStream.write(json.getBytes());
   outputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Data class :

```
 public class Data {

        private Map<String, Map<String, String>> map;

        public Data() {

        }

        public Data(Map<String, Map<String, String>> map) {
            this.map = map;
        }

        public Map<String, Map<String, String>> getMap() {
            return map;
        }

        public void setMap(Map<String, Map<String, String>> map) {
            this.map = map;
        }

    }
```

My problem is that I need to create the file once and then check if the file exists, if it does I need to check if config1 exists if it doesn't I need to put config1 in the file.

But I can't check if config1 exists because I get :
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.Map com.a.app.ui.app.appFragment$Data.getMap()`

I check if it exists by doing :

```
Boolean configTest = data.getMap().containsKey("config1");
if(!configTest){}
```

How can I create the file and check the data without getting a NullPointerException ?

Comment: is maps inside your JSON an array?, also in your Data class the field should be "maps" or just change the JSON data maps to "map"

Comment: no it's not but when config1 is in the file I can get it with `data.getMap().get("config1") `

Comment: if you only  want to check that if it exists or not? then create JSONObject j = new JSONObject(your_json_string); then simple use the method, j.has("config1");

Answer (score 1):

I think you should modify the way you're handling things.

First create `POJO` for `Config1` each values as:

```
// file Config1.java

public class Config1
{
    private String component1;

    private String component2;

    private String component3;

    public String getComponent1 ()
    {
        return component1;
    }

    public void setComponent1 (String component1)
    {
        this.component1 = component1;
    }

    public String getComponent2 ()
    {
        return component2;
    }

    public void setComponent2 (String component2)
    {
        this.component2 = component2;
    }

    public String getComponent3 ()
    {
        return component3;
    }

    public void setComponent3 (String component3)
    {
        this.component3 = component3;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [component1 = "+component1+", component2 = "+component2+", component3 = "+component3+"]";
    }
}
```

And then after that `POJO` for `Config2`

```
// file Config2.java
public class Config2
{
    private String component1;

    private String component2;

    private String component3;

    public String getComponent1 ()
    {
        return component1;
    }

    public void setComponent1 (String component1)
    {
        this.component1 = component1;
    }

    public String getComponent2 ()
    {
        return component2;
    }

    public void setComponent2 (String component2)
    {
        this.component2 = component2;
    }

    public String getComponent3 ()
    {
        return component3;
    }

    public void setComponent3 (String component3)
    {
        this.component3 = component3;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [component1 = "+component1+", component2 = "+component2+", component3 = "+component3+"]";
    }
}
```

And then you need `POJO` for `Maps`

```
// file Maps.java
public class Maps
{
    private Config2 config2;

    private Config1 config1;

    public Config2 getConfig2 ()
    {
        return config2;
    }

    public void setConfig2 (Config2 config2)
    {
        this.config2 = config2;
    }

    public Config1 getConfig1 ()
    {
        return config1;
    }

    public void setConfig1 (Config1 config1)
    {
        this.config1 = config1;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [config2 = "+config2+", config1 = "+config1+"]";
    }
}
```

And finally the `class` which will wrap everything up `MyJsonPojo`. Though you can rename it to whatever you want.

```
// file MyJsonPojo.java
public class MyJsonPojo
{
    private Maps maps;

    public Maps getMaps ()
    {
        return maps;
    }

    public void setMaps (Maps maps)
    {
        this.maps = maps;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [maps = "+maps+"]";
    }
}
```

Finally replace your code in the `loadData()` method as:

```
public void load() throws IOException {

        File file = getContext().getFileStreamPath("jsonfile.txt");
        
        FileInputStream fis = getContext().openFileInput("jsonfile.txt");
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(isr);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }

        String json = sb.toString();

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Data data = gson.fromJson(json, MyJsonPojo.class);

        Maps maps = data.getMaps();
        Config1 config1 = null;

        if (maps != null) {
            config1 = maps.getConfig1()
        }

        if (config1 != null) {
            componentURL = config1.getComponent1();
        }

}
```

For saving the values you can do this:

```
public void save() {

    // set url here
    Component1 component1 = new Component1();
    component1.setComponent1(itemUrl);
    
    // store it in maps
    Maps maps = new Maps();
    maps.setComponent1(component1);

    // finally add it to the MyJsonPojo instance
    MyJsonPojo myJsonPojo = new MyJsonPojo();
    myJsonPojo.setMaps(maps);
    
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(maps);
    
    String filename = "jsonfile.txt";
    
    FileOutputStream outputStream;
    
    try {
       outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
       outputStream.write(json.getBytes());
       outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Please note that you may have to modify the `save()` code as per your structure because I am quite unsure about how you have handled what in the code. I have provided the basic implementation without much proof reading my code.